# Android application catching unwanted exception

Tags: android, exception, try-catch, if-statement

I'm writing a simple app which allows a user to enter their income and it deducts tax, then saves the amount in a file for future reference. The problem is that if I try to enter anything in the 'postTax' editText, it will throw the bottom exception. I'm obviously doing something stupid with my logic but can anyone see the problem?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {

        if (preTax !=null){ 

            Double incomeAmount = Double.parseDouble(preTax.getText().toString());
            incomeAmount = incomeAmount - (0.2 *incomeAmount);      
            Double incomeRounded = Round(incomeAmount);
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Your income minus tax = "+incomeRounded, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String storeIncome = Double.toString(incomeRounded);

            try{
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("income", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
                osw.write(storeIncome);

                osw.flush();
                osw.close();

            } catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error writing to file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        else if (postTax!=null){

            Double incomeAmount = Double.parseDouble(postTax.getText().toString());
            Double incomeRounded = Round(incomeAmount);
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Your income is: "+ incomeRounded, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String storeIncome = Double.toString(incomeRounded);


            try{
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("income", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);

                osw.write(storeIncome);
                osw.flush();
                osw.close();

            } catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error writing to file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Please fill in the relevant catagories", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's totally expected. The line:

```
 Double incomeAmount = Double.parseDouble(postTax.getText().toString());
```

can throw `NumberFormatException` if number entered in `postTax` edit doesn't parse to `double`. The bottom `catch` is the closest one to capture this exception.

Put this line (along with few subsequent ones) inside the `try-catch` block a little below to have the exception caught there. (You will likely want to change the toast message though, into something like "Failed to process post tax value").

Comment: Ah! You are right. I don't understand why this is causing a NumberFormatException however, the data I am entering is the same as for the preTax and that doesn't throw an exception?

Comment: By the logic of your `if` construct, the `postTax` part will not be even executed if there is a `preTax` variable set (which, I assume, is a reference to some `EditText`). Thinking about it, that's what might be the main reason of unexpected/errornous behavior of your code.